# Computing centimeter-per-pixel distortions caused by wide angle / short focal length lens based on camera height

Tags: python, camera, computer-vision, intrinsics, distortion

Given an overhead camera with a field-of-view angle `fov`, a mounting height in centimeters `height`, and a frame `image`, I can compute the minimum and maximum length side of a bounding box (in pixels) for detecting people using the following piece of code:

```
def min_max_area(img, height, fov):
    """
    Use height (in centimeters) to determine the appropriate minimum and
    maximum pixel area for detecting people.
    """
    min_cm_width = 30  # female forearm-to-forearm is about 45 cm
    max_cm_width = 70  # male forearm-to-forearm is about 55 cm

    avg_person_height = 169

    # get real distance of camera view width and centimeters per pixel
    x = (height - avg_person_height) * math.tan(math.radians(fov/2)) * 2
    cm_per_pixel = x / img.shape[1]

    # determine minimum and maximum edge length of bounding box
    min_pixel_width = min_cm_width / cm_per_pixel
    max_pixel_width = max_cm_width / cm_per_pixel

    return min_pixel_width**2, max_pixel_width**2
```

This works fine for standard focal length lens or short focal length lens mounted at a higher distance from the floor. For example, I've tested with a 106 degree FOV camera mounted at 274 centimeters and that's OK. A 60-70 degree FOV lens mounted at 209 centimeters works fine but cannot capture a large enough field of view to be useful meaning a solution that uses a wide-angle lens instead is required.

However, when I use a 170 degree FOV camera mounted at 209 centimeters, the bounding boxes are much too small to detect a person standing underneath the camera. The problem persists using the 106 degree FOV camera, although it's not as pronounced.

Here is a screenshot of the 170 degree FOV camera mounted at 209 centimeters -- the red and black squares are the incorrectly computed minimum and maximum bounding boxes, respectively:
[image]

My thoughts are that:

- there must be some math to scale the bounding box size
- using the FOV / given focal length may or may not be sufficient
- if FOV / given focal length are not sufficient, computing the camera's intrinsic parameters hopefully will be
- when a contour is discovered, use its radial distance from the optical center (in combination with the camera matrix?) to dynamically compute cms/pixel instead of assuming a constant ratio across the whole image

I think [this link](https://pgaleone.eu/computer-vision/2019/01/18/camera-setup-measurement/) may contain information relevant to my needs but I'm not sure...what camera parameters (if any) are necessary to scale a bounding box (if possible) to correct cm/pixel distortions? If possible, what general form might an equation take which achieves this?

Comment: Please add Python tag.
To your question:
As you have found out by yourself, it is current a topic of research of how to handle distorted images, especially for wide angle taken images. Since you want to use your snippet for dynamic images, I would recommend you to normalize distorted parts (idk how) apply your BB and convert it back.

If you know a good paper which handles that distortion, please tell me :)